# What is the average minimum value in a set of 100 integers chosen at random uniformly and independently in the range 0-99 inclusive?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, uniform-distribution, average

Obviously the smallest possible value is 0, but 0 isn't guaranteed to be in the set. I'd assume that most of the time the minimum value would be either 0 or 1, which would make the average minimum be 0.5, but there are also the cases where there is a larger minimum. Of course, the higher the minimum for a specific set, the less likely it is for the set to be chosen, so I'd guess the actual average is a bit more than 0.5, maybe around 0.58. I'm just not sure how to find this value mathematically.

Comment: Maybe related: [distribution of the sample minimum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/220) (not the average minimum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the average minimum value in a set of 100 integers chosen at random uniformly and independently in the range 0-99 inclusive?

For $n \in \{0,1,2\cdots,99\}$, 
let $f(n)$ denote the probability that the minimum number selected is $n$.

Here it is assumed that the numbers are selected in accordance with the excerpted paragraph, at the start of this answer.

Then, the computation for the average minimum is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{99} n \times f(n). \tag1 $$

Therefore, the problem reduces to computing $f(n)$.

---

For $n \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,99\}$ 
Let $g(n)$ denote the probability that each of the selected numbers is $\geq n$.

Here $g(n)$ includes the cases where each of the numbers is strictly $> n$.

Then, for illustrative purposes

- $g(0) = 1$
- $\displaystyle g(99) = \left[\frac{1}{100}\right]^{100}.$

Then, you have that in general,

$$g(n) = \left[\frac{100 - n}{100}\right]^{100}.$$

Then,

- $f(99) = g(99)$.
- For $n \in \{0,1,2\cdots,98\} ~: ~f(n) = g(n) - g(n+1).$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation of (1) above}}$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{99} n \times f(n) = \left\{ ~\sum_{n = 0}^{98} \left[n \times [g(n) - g(n+1)\right] ~\right\} + \left[99 \times \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{100}\right]$$

$$= \left\{ ~\sum_{n = 0}^{98} \left[n \times \left(\frac{100 - n}{100}\right)^{100} - n \times \left(\frac{99 - n}{100}\right)^{100}\right] ~\right\} + \left[99 \times \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{100}\right]. \tag2 $$

(2) above can be simplified by algebraic manipulation, to

$$0 \times \left(\frac{100}{100}\right)^{100} 
+ \sum_{n=1}^{99} \left(\frac{100 - n}{100}\right)^{100}. \tag3 $$

For me, part of the challenge of the problem is stretching my intuition around the expression in (3) above.  In effect, each incremental probability computation of

$~\displaystyle \left(\frac{100 - n}{100}\right)^{100}$

adds $(+1)$ to the expected minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ denote this minimum value. The exact formula for its mean is
$$E(X)=\sum_{k \ge 1} P(X \ge k)=   \sum_{k =1}^{99} (1-\frac{k}{100})^{100}\,.$$
A good approximation is
$$\sum_{k \ge 1} e^{-k}=\frac{1}{e-1}=0.5819\ldots\,.$$

Comment: @user2661923: It is, but the summation actually equals $\frac{1}{e-1}$, I think...

Comment: @BrianTung I pocket calculated the first $4$ non-zero terms, starting at $k=1$.  It does look like $(0.5819)$ is a good approximation.

Comment: @BrianTung That was a typo, corrected, thanks.

Comment: A one-liner in R to check this: `mean(replicate(10^6, min(sample(0:99, 100, TRUE))))` returns (when I run it) 0.572872, compared to 0.5721141 for the exact value.